# How to use orderByChild('status').equalTo('onTheWay') in Javascript in Web version 9 Module

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to filter data from Firebase realtime database by child value
But i am not able to do as it was simple to do in web version 8
How can i achieve

i tried below

```
get(ref(database, 'Orders/'), orderByChild('status').equalTo('onTheWay')).then((snapshot) =>{
   //my code here
});
```

it gives me the following error

> orderByChild(...).equalTo is not a function

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `query()` function to build a query and pass each clause as a separate argument in it instead of chaining them. Try refactoring your code as shown below:

```
import { getDatabase, get, ref, query, orderByChild, equalTo } from "firebase/database";

const q = query(ref(db, 'Orders/'), orderByChild('status'), equalTo('onTheWay'));

get(q).then(snapshot => {
  console.log(q)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the Solution. I got the Rules error that i fixed by the following solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53295841/the-proper-way-of-adding-an-index-in-a-nested-firebase-realtime-database-structu