# How to make a query on nested keys in a Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to build a leaderboard for my users inside my realtime db.

That's the structure of my db:

```
_firebase_db_url {
  users: {
     user1: {
        displayName: "name", 
        ...some_other_infos...
        games: {
           game1: {
               lastScore: 123,
               timePlayed: 120
           }, 
           game2: {
               lastScore: 456,
               timePlayed: 360
           },
           ...
        }
     }
  },
  games: {
      0 : {
         "id": "game1", 
         "description": "..."
      },
      1 : {
         "id": "game1", 
         "description": "..."
      },
      ...
}
```

What I'm trying to do is making a query on the db to get max 10 player ordered by lastScore on a certain game.

I've tried so far:

```
db.ref('/users')
  .orderByChild(`lastScore`)
  .limitToFirst(10)
  .get()
  .then((val) => console.log(val.val()));
```

This prints my users but not ordered by game scores

I've also tried to make a loop on all games and then the query on the db:

```
   db.ref('/games')
     .get()
     .then(
       (result) => {
         const gamesList = result.val();
         const gamesIdsArray = []
         Object.values(gamesList)
           .forEach(game => {
               gamesIdsArray.push(game.id)
           })
         return gamesIdsArray;
       }).then(   // Once I got entirely my array filled with the games ID, I proceed
         (gamesIdsArray) => {
            gamesIdsArray.forEach(gameId => {
            db.ref('/users')
              .orderByChild(`lastScore`)
              .limitToFirst(10)
              .get()
              .then((val) => console.log(val.val()))
            })
         }
       )
```

This prints for the number of games all my users not ordered by games. (It prints the users also if them don't have the specific game obj: if I'm looping on `game5` the query prints 10 users including users that don't have the filed `game5` inside their `games` section).

Other tries:

```
 db.ref('/users')
   .child('games')
   .child(`${req.userId}/games/${gameId}`) //passing the userId inside my https.onRequest() function
   .orderByChild(`lastScore`)
   .limitToFirst(10)
   .get()
   .then((val) => console.log(val.val()))
```

Still nothing useful

```
db.ref('/users/{userId}/games{gameId}/lastScore')
   .orderByChild(`lastScore`)
   .limitToFirst(10)
   .get()
   .then((val) => console.log(val.val()))
```

Still nothing useful

I've also included in my realtime db rules all the `.indexOn` I've tried so far.
Nothing helped.

What am I doing wrong?
What should I try?
Should I switch to Firestore to keep user data?

---

[ EDITED ]

I've slightly edited my db set as follows based on [Frank's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76721927/209103):

```
db {
    users: {
        "user1": {
            name: "name1",
            ... some other infos
        },
        "user2": {
            name: "name2",
            ... some other infos
        },
        ...
    }
    games: {
        "game1": {
            "user1": {
                bestScore: 123
            },
            "user2": {
                bestScore: 234
            }
        },
        "game2": {
            "user1": {
                bestScore: 765
            },
            "user2": {
                bestScore: 543
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Query that prints the users but not ordered:

```
db.ref("games")
  .child(gameId) //getting my gameId var from request.data.gameId from my onCall function
  .orderByChild("bestScore")
  .once('value', (res) => {
      console.log(res.val())
      return res.val()
   })
```

And still getting the users not ordered

---

Comment: What do you mean by "on a certain game"?

Comment: @AlexMamo as you see in my database I want to make a leaderboard for each game (game1, game2 and so on)

Comment: Can you share the snapshot of your db ?

Comment: Your database structure is will not scale and for your current query to be excuted correctly you will need index on `lastScores` field according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53302804/20239914) as your `lastScores` resides inside a dynamic node which cannot be indexed statically you will have to change your db structure as explained in that answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @RohitKharche of which query?

Comment: @nico_1512 Your 2nd query is getting failed because you need index to be made on `bestScore` which you can do as follows : "games" : { ".indexOn" : ["bestScore"] } inside the database.rules file.

Comment: @RohitKharche I already have the `.indexOn` in my db rules

Comment: @RohitKharche in the edited section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're combining data of multiple entity types (users, and game scores) under your `users` branch, which goes against Firebase's guidance on [structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data), specifically the section on [keeping the data structure flat](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#flatten_data_structures).

To allow your query, add an additional top-level node, where you track the scores of various users for a specific game. Something like this:

```
game_user_scores: {
  "game1": {
    "user1": {
      lastScore: 123,
      timePlayed: 120
    },
    ...
  },
  "game2": {
    "user1": {
      lastScore: 456,
      timePlayed: 360
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Now you can query the top scorers for a specific game with:

```
db.ref("users")
  .child("game_user_scores/game1")
  .orderByChild("lastScore")
  .limitToFirst(10)
```

---

Your second problem is caused by the fact that you use `val()` immediately on the result. That gets the result as a JSON value, and there's no room for ordering information in that.

To process the results in order, use the built-in `forEach` method of the snapshot you get back:

```
((res) => {
  res.forEach((snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val())
  });
})
```

Comment: @frankvonpuffelen checl my update please

Comment: thanks so much! I've solved the problem with the same code form another answare (also made by you)